# Syncing multiple scrollviews in RecycleView Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm new to android development and have been learning how to build apps in android studio using kotlin.

Part of the project I'm working on uses a RecyclerView. The items being dispalyed by the recyclerView each have a scroll view. I want to set it up so that the scrolling on all the scrollviews are synced.

My solution was to add a onScrollChangeListener to each of the scrollViews and store the position in a LiveData variable. I then add an observer to the LiveData variable and then when ever I detect a change I'll cycle through all the scrollViews in the recyclerView and move them to the correct position.

Currently I can only get it to start wroking after I add an item to the recyclerView, however when I close the app and start it again I'll have to add another item to the recyclerView before it can work again.

Here is my code in my MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val dataViewModel: DataViewModel by viewModels {
        DataViewModelFactory((application as DataApplication).repository)
    }

    var vsvPosition: MutableLiveData<Int?> = MutableLiveData()

    fun updateScrollPosition(scrollY: Int){
        vsvPosition!!.value = scrollY
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val container = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.calendar_recyclerview)
        val calendarRecyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.calendar_recyclerview)
        val calendarAdapter = WeekListAdapter()

        calendarRecyclerView.adapter = calendarAdapter
        calendarRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)

        vsvPosition.observe(this, Observer<Int?> {
            for (i in 0 until container.childCount) {
                val vsv = container.getChildAt(i)
                    .findViewById<ScrollView>(R.id.dayScrollView)
                vsv.smoothScrollTo(0, it!!)
            }
        })

        dataViewModel.allappointments.observe(this, Observer { appointments ->
            appointments?.let {
                notificationAdapter.submitList(it)
                calendarAdapter.submitList(it)

                  for (i in 0 until container.childCount) {
                      val hsv = container.getChildAt(i)
                          .findViewById<ScrollView>(R.id.dayScrollView)
  
                      if (hsv != null){
                          Log.d("kl1","scrollview found")
                          vsv.setOnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->
                              vsvPosition!!.value = scrollY
                          }
                      }
                  }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated